# Regex - Nested matches

Tags: regex

When the following regex - `\d\[\w*]` is given the input string - `asd3[bc]de` , it would match `3[bc]`.
When given input such as `3[bc4[de]]` that has nested matches, it matches the inner pattern `4[de]` and not the outer one. Why is this so? Is there a way to force the regex to match the outer pattern?

Comment: For matching nested content you may need to write your own parser.

Comment: Which tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: The most obvious reason to your question of why it fails to match the outer group is because neither `[` nor `]` is in the set `\w` (i.e. character class).  One possible pattern to match the outer group would be `\d\[(\w|[\[\]])*]`

Comment: @blhsing tried on rubular.com ... you bring up a good point though...whenever I have to do something with regex, I just try out with such tools first, with the idea that regexes would behave the same across languages (havent really put much thought to it)...which might not always be the case (I am not sure to what extent regex implementation varies between languages, but I'd assume differences would be subtle if any)

Comment: @CPerkins you hit the bull's eye there

Comment: @AadithRamia  Yeah, but I just realized the example pattern I gave is not "complete".  It allows mismatched sets of brackets and was only to demonstrate how to resolve the immediate failure for the given text.  Matching paired delimiters is much more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\w` won't match a '['.

The `\d\[` matches the `3[`, then `\w*` matches `bc4`, but won't match the inner '['.  So, the regex engine has to back track and find another match for `\d\[`.  That matches the `4[`, `\w*` matches `de`, and then the `]`s match.

I believe there are some regex engines that can have recursive patterns and match nested items.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let re = /\d\[\w*]?(\d\[\w*])]/;
let str = "3[bc4[de]]";
console.log([...str.match(re)]);
```